# NOW() in ServiceStack.OrmLite

Tags: c#, mysql, ormlite-servicestack

Question is in the title.
I have T4 generated objects, but how would I Save() or Update() an object while setting its "LastAccess" property to the sql function "NOW()"?

I don't want DateTime.UtcNow, I want the sql server to set the time!

Can this be done without writing any sql except for maybe the now() part? Like only using the extension functions / sql query builder in OrmLite?